# Java Spring Boot/Mysql - Doing a query with a HashSet as a Parameter

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa

I'm doing a Spring Boot application with JPA and I have and object (let's call it `Conversation`) which has a property that is a `HashSet` of another object (`User`). In the `ConversationRepository` there's the following method:

```
@Query("SELECT c FROM Conversation c WHERE ?1 MEMBER OF c.users
Conversation findByUsers(Set<User> users);
```

However, when I try to use this query passing a `HashSet` of `User` as parameter (which it has two users stored), there's a `SQLException (1241)` which says that the operand should contain 2 columns.

What is the correct way to do a query with a `HashSet` as a parameter?

Comment: Your `@Query` looks incomplete. Also post the full stack trace not just a message.

Comment: What should the query do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your method is not passing the first parameter value. Your query expecting two inputs and your method signature has only one. try passing the value for ?1.

Modify your query like

@Query("SELECT c FROM Conversation c WHERE :value MEMBER OF c.users

Conversation findByUsers(User value, Set users);